# How to change the class when I hover over an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I am really new on JS or in any other programming language and this is my first post on Stackoverflow; Having said that, I apologize in advance for any mystake and let's go to the question.

I have this code and I need to change the classes of the `li` and the `i` elements with only one hover.

What I want is make both of them change their colors when I hover over them (the thing about the colors is just an example, as a matter of fact I will have to make some more changes), for example, If I hover over the `li`, the `i` also has its color changed and vice versa.

I provided two examples in my codepen, in the first one I selected the `li` and the `i` elements and in the second I selected the `a` element, all of them with their respective classes.

In the first one when I hover over the `li` its color changes but the `i` doesn't suffer any alteration and if I hover over the `i` it changes, but the `li` is kept the same.

In short, I need exactly the same effect of the codepen, but I need it happening with the text (`li`) and with the arrow(`i`) at the same time.

About the second example, it doesn't work well.

p.s. It is important that once an item has received the class `active`, it only backs to its original class when another item receives the hover and becomes `active`, if the cursor is moved to any other part of the screen then the item should hold the class, so that there is always an item with the class `active`.

https://codepen.io/WegisSilveira/pen/qzMqxj

```
    <ul>
    <a href="">
      <li class="test">Banheiro</li>
      <i class=" test ">&#62;</i>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="test active">Cozinha</li>
      <i class=" test">&#62;</i>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="test">Quarto</li>
      <i class="test">&#62;</i>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="test">Varanda</li>
      <i class=" test ">&#62;</i>
    </a>
</ul>

<h1>-------------------------</h1>

<ul>
    <a class="classA active" href="">
      <li >Banheiro</li>
      <i >&#62;</i>
    </a>
    <a class="classA" href="">
      <li >Cozinha</li>
      <i >&#62;</i>
    </a>
    <a class="classA" href="">
      <li >Quarto</li>
      <i >&#62;</i>
    </a>
    <a class="classA" href="">
      <li >Varanda</li>
      <i >&#62;</i>
    </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and take it out of the code box so its easier to read?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you want, so two answers for two different interpretations of your Q:

### Applied to each Element Individually

Based on [Mobly's site navbar](https://www.mobly.com.br/), you would want to essentially apply a rule for each element via CSS and/or JS/Jquery (note these are two seperate approaches, you can use either/or, though the CSS approach would usually be preferred):

CSS (or you can just change color instead of opacity):

```
.test {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    /* transition: opacity 0.5s; optional fun effect*/
}
.test:hover {
    /* this would essentially be your active class */
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

JS Approach (w/Jquery; you can do it without Jquery, just more words to select):

```
$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().addClass("active");
}, function() {
  $(this).children().removeClass("active");
});
```

### Using Siblings

CSS, standing for Cascading Style Sheets, cannot work backwards, but can work "sideways" to siblings. In CSS this is done with [sibling selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp):

```
.test:hover, .test:hover ~ i {
    color: red;
}
```

JS

```
$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().addClass("active");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

### Persistency of Class

> It is important that once an item has received the class 'active', it
>   only backs to its original class when another item receives the hover
>   and becomes 'active'

To add a persistent class that only changes when another element becomes active, remove the event handler for hoveroff and instead remove the active class of  all elements with the .active class:

[Example Jquery](https://codepen.io/seraphendipity/pen/dBqZNq):

```
$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().addClass("active");
});
```

---

### Other Recommendations

- Instead of the `<ul>`, use the more semantically correct `<nav>` with only `<a>` tags underneath.
- Use class instead of id; usually default to class unless you need id attribute.

**NOTE TO OP: Let me know which sections actually helped answer your question specifically and I'll delete or strike through the rest.**

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense. I'll try that and let you know if worked.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the edit, as I said, it is my first post and I didn't understand what it was at first, but I fixed the grammatical erros. As the last paragraph, I put that there because I am not sure if I am being clear on my post and that can serve as an example. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, it's me who should apologizes for not being able to provide a clear question. We are in the right way, but is missing something. With the "Hover over the Parent" option I got close of what I need, the difference is because I want to apply the class only on the item that is being hovered, not on all of them. I edited my question and my codepen archive as well. I appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well. The last two topics (using siblings and persistency of class) have helped me to accomplish what I wanted. I appreciate your time and patience, you helped a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <span id="my-id" class="one">Element</span>

  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      // attach event handler so that when you hover over it you change the class
      $('#my-id').hover(function() {
        // first remove class "one"
        $(this).removeClass('one');

        // next add class "two"
        $(this).addClass('two');

        // OR if you want to add and remove the same class you can use toggle
        $(this).toggleClass('one'); // this will add "one" class if it is not there or remove it if it is there
      });
    });

  </script>
</html>
```

The reason your code isn't working is that all your elements are sharing the same id. Put the "diamond" ID into the class attribute and remove the ID attribute from your elements.
ID is meant to be unique.

```
<ul>
  <a href="" >
    <li class="test active"</li>
    <i class="flaticon-right-arrow test activeI"></i>
    <i class="diamond flaticon-diamond"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="test">Banheiro</li>
    <i class="flaticon-right-arrow testI "></i>
    <i class="diamond flaticon-diamond"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li class="test">Cozinha</li>
    <i class="flaticon-right-arrow testI "></i>
    <i class="diamond flaticon-diamond"></i>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello, friend. Thank you. I already did that with JS, but I need to do with the three element simultaneously. Is that any way I can do that?

Comment: you can't have an ID attached to 3 elements. Put "diamond" in the class attribute. IDs are unique.

Comment: I see, you're right. This is because I just had the code duplicated. But I wasn't using this second icon in my tests, just the first one with the class 'testI'

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp), you can learn there how to use `.removeClass()` `.addClass()` and `.toggleClass()` jQuery methods. I highly recommend you to use jQuery instead plain JavaScript.

But the way, if you want to change the color is more efficient to use CSS than JS, you use that as follow:

```
.class{
   color: red;
}
.class:hover {
   color:blue;
}
```

There all the elements that have the class `.class` will be red, but when you enter the mouse in the element it will be blue ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do that. The problem is that I don't just want to change the color, I really need to change classes. The thing about red was just an example. And yes, I'll use JQuery, but now I am studying plain Javascript, I believe learning plain JS first will provide me a better understanding of the logics of the language. OH, and I wasn't able to open the link, I guess it is not working. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link. I strongly recommend the page I'm sharing to start to learn JS, Jquery, css... it's the w3chools page

Comment: Ow, of course. I know w3school, I found it on Google and since then I use it all the time. Good to know that it is a great website. Thank you very much!